# How to add a variable integer to filename of csv in c

Tags: c, csv

I want to add a variable integer into the filename of a csv in the C-language. I am using this line of code to do that:

```
errCode = TG_SetDataLog(connectionId, "dataLog%d.csv", i);
```

If the `errCode = 0`, than the function `TG_SetDataLog` will write data to a csv. I thougt i could add a variable by using `%d` and put the variable behind the comma, but this does not work. The following information is what i can get about the `TG_SetDataLog` function.

[image]

If someone could help me it would be really helpfull.

Comment: Use `sprintf` to write to a buffer first (using the %d syntax above), then pass the buffer into `TG_SetDataLog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char buff[64];

sprintf(buff, "dataLog%d.csv", i);
errCode = TG_SetDataLog(connectionId, buff);
```

`sprintf` (or `snprintf` that is better because secure) is like printf, but write in a buffer, not on the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

`TG_SetDataLog` is not a variadic function which supports the `printf` %d syntax.

You need to do it in two steps, as follows:

```
char buffer[32]; 
sprintf(buffer,"dataLog%d.csv",i); 
errCode = TG_SetDataLog(connectionId, buffer);
```